# Show me sample XML for this XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to write valid XML for this schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="resourceType">
    <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <documentation>
            A resource root within a deployment.
        </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="filter" type="filterType" minOccurs="0">
            <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <documentation>
                    A path filter specification for this resource root (optional). By default all paths are accepted.
                </documentation>
            </annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
        <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <documentation>
                The name of this resource root (optional). If not specified, defaults to the value of the path
                attribute.
            </documentation>
        </annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="path" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <documentation>
                The path of this resource root, relative to the path in which the module.xml file is found.
            </documentation>
        </annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I am new to XML and XSD, and I will be grateful for little help: What would be an example XML document that would be valid according to this XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that prevent any XML from being valid against your XSD as provided:

1. The XSD includes a reference to an undefined type, `filterType`.
2. The XSD specifies no root element.

By replacing `filterType` with `xsd:string` and adding a root element, `r` of type equal to the top-level complexType in your XSD, then this modified XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="r" type="resourceType"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="resourceType">
    <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <documentation>
        A resource root within a deployment.
      </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="filter" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
        <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <documentation>
            A path filter specification for this resource root
            (optional). By default all paths are accepted.
          </documentation>
        </annotation>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
      <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <documentation>
          The name of this resource root (optional). If not specified,
          defaults to the value of the path attribute.
        </documentation>
      </annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="path" type="xsd:string" use="required">
      <annotation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <documentation>
          The path of this resource root, relative to the path in
          which the module.xml file is found.
        </documentation>
      </annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

would successfully validate the following XML, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r path="">
  <filter/>
</r>
```